# One game center account for two iOS apps

Tags: iphone, game-center

Anyone knows what I need to do to have both my free and paid versions feed the same Game Center leader board?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that's not possible, because the Game Center uses the application's "bundle identifier" (such as com.myCompany.myCoolGame) to identify a game -- and two apps cannot have the same identifier.

That's at least the status in iOS 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

Provide a complete app, but disable features. Then use an in-app purchase to unlock these functionality. This way, 'both' Apps will have the same identifier.

Comment: Rene, could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Deliver an app, with a limited set of features disabled. Which will be unlocked when you do an in-app-purchase. (store this as a property with the app, boolean), and check with if-else when it is unlocked

Answer (score 2):

Starting from iOS 6.0 there is a functionality called Game Center Groups. You can set these groups in iTunes Connect and assign multiple applications to them. This way they can share leaderboards and achievements.